# C macro expansion not working but writing that line explicitly worked

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

```
//#define newScope(string, scopeType) ({ \
        intrprtr.scope = realloc(intrprtr.scope, intrprtr.scope_layer*sizeof(struct Scope)); \
        strncpy(intrprtr.scope[intrprtr.scope_layer-1].string, (string), 255); \
        intrprtr.scope[intrprtr.scope_layer-1].scopeType = (scopeType); \
        })
            //newScope(string, objScope);    // <-- wanted to use macro but it doesn't work. I don't get it
            intrprtr.scope = realloc(intrprtr.scope, intrprtr.scope_layer*sizeof(struct Scope)); 
            strncpy(intrprtr.scope[intrprtr.scope_layer-1].string, string, 255); 
            intrprtr.scope[intrprtr.scope_layer-1].scopeType = objScope;   // <-- this worked
```

I wanted the code to be more readable, so I used a macro to wrap us to code. I got the following error if I used the macro.

```
src/parser.c:114:30: error: no member named 'objScope' in 'struct Scope'
            newScope(string, objScope);    // <-- wanted to use macro but it doesn't work. I don't get it
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
src/parser.c:109:48: note: expanded from macro 'newScope'
        intrprtr.scope[intrprtr.scope_layer-1].scopeType = (scopeType); \
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
```

I did not get this error if I write the code explicitly.
Here is the declaration of intrprtr (in parser.h that I included in parser.c)

```
typedef struct{
    FILE* file;
    char cur_file_name[255];
    int line_num;
    struct Scope {
        char string[255];
        enum ScopeType { msgScope, objScope, codeBlock, func } scopeType;
    }*scope;
    int scope_layer;
}Intrprtr;
extern Intrprtr intrprtr;
```

According to my understanding, when I passed `objScope` to second argument of `newScope` macro, `scopeType` should expand to `objScope`. i.e.
`intrprtr.scope[intrprtr.scope_layer-1].scopeType = objScope;`
That no member error doesn't make any sense to me especially when `intrprtr.scope[intrprtr.scope_layer-1].scopeType = objScope;` actually worked. Can someone explain this for me? Thanks

Comment: Using `-E` option of your compiler (Assuming it is supported), does it show the same line which works otherwise?

Comment: Using `string` as a macro parameter identifier looks very risky.

Comment: Kind of, but not the `-o`. Try `gcc -E src/main.c` for the .c file in which you try the macro.

Comment: And the reason why you can't use a super-readable function is...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the replacement tokens `intrprtr.scope[intrprtr.scope_layer-1].scopeType = (scopeType);`, the `scopeType` token is replaced by the corresponding macro argument, `objScope`, both times it appears, but you want the first one to be a literal member name `scopeType`, not to be replaced.

Change the macro parameter name to something that is not otherwise used in the replacement tokens.

Comment: I almost had it, just nagged about the wrong parameter... I usually avoid this by always using `ParString` and similar, i.e. always be totally blunt and explicit about "this is a parameter".